# Elasticsearch keyword + range query (V-6.2)

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, range, elasticsearch-6

I am trying to write a query in Elasticsearch to make it work with Range filter and query keyword input from user. 
The query that I end up writing is:

```
"size": val, //default 10,
"from": 0, //default 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": search_query //Val coming from user input
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "lastmodifieddate": {
                        "gte": '2016-12-09T00:00:00',
                        "lte": '2016-12-20T00:00:00'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above query is not working.

Also I am looking for matching 1 of the key value pair  from my elasticsearch.

```
_source:
    lastmodifieddate: "2016-12-07T18:34:48.000+0000",
    ..
    ..
    fileType: "PDF"
    ...
```

Can someone throw some light on how to make it work and also a query parameter with all records must match fileType = PDF

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You must put "filter" outside "must". Both of them are in different context. See this documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "user input" 
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "lastmodifieddate": {
                    "gte": "2014-01-09T00:00:00",
                    "lte": "2014-12-20T00:00:00"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```